# Django Microsoft Office 365 Login

Tags: python, django, authentication, oauth, office365

I am currently working with a team to develop a web application for my college using the Django framework. We primarily use Office 365, so I have been looking for a solution to use Office 365 authentication to authenticate users of our application. I have not found anything that can achieve this.

Note: I have used social-auth to allow users to login with Google, but this is only temporary until I find a way to use Office 365. Any suggestions will be wonderful!

Comment: The Office 365 management api utilizes Azure active directory and there are both commercial auth clients like Auth0 that provide 0auth linking to a django application and Azure AD. I would read through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/get-started-with-office-365-management-apis  then determine if this the direction you want to go. There are also py libraries for this https://pypi.org/project/django-azure-ad-auth/. I have never done this so that's as far as I can steer you.

Comment: link to service solution https://auth0.com/authenticate/django/azure-active-directory/

Comment: There is also a provider for `django-allauth` at https://github.com/Lamelos/django-allauth-office365