# Django office365

Tags: django, office365api

How can we add office365 login to our django application login? So I need to add some authentication to my user in django. And similarly how would I be able to use this user in the request parameter.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52637161/django-microsoft-office-365-login) helps